# Swing aplication Google maps geocoding with oracle

Tags: java, swing, google-maps-api-3

According to this site [degenio.com/...](http://www.degenio.com/2009/01/oracle-forms-10g-using-static-google-maps-with-http-geocoding-service/) Oracle has created a cool bean which can show google maps on a swing application starting from a street and address.
I downloaded gmap.jar and created a project inside NetBeans however I don't know where to find oracle.forms.ui.VBean, oracle.forms.properties.ID, oracle.forms.handler.IHandler. oracle.forms.ui.CustomEvent.

Somebody suggested to download the library here [oracle/...](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/downloads/index.html) however it's a 1.8 GB file and it sounds like a library for JavaEE and not Java Standard Edition.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Do you really need to use Oracle Forms? If not, I'd recommend to look at JavaFX. Here is an example: http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/maps-in-javafx-2-0/

Comment: I'm developing a Swing Interface, so I cannot use JavaFX.

Comment: You *could* use this Swing component to include JavaFX components in Swing applications: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html . Also note that in order to use Oracle Forms, you will need to acquire a license from Oracle...